# SQL Server Stored Procedure with multiple batches - reuse of temp table

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016

I have a short SQL script which has been in use for a bit. It reuses a temp table within a script and has been working nicely.

Recently, I decided that I'm going to stick this whole thing into a procedure, though I had a surprise waiting for me - there's a use of the keyword `GO` in order to divide the script into two batches (that is how I was able to reuse the temp table) - which is why SQL Server is barking at me.

Here is a dumbed down script displaying the functionality of the script:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temp;
SELECT
    'john' AS first_name
    ,'doe' AS last_name
INTO #temp;

SELECT * FROM #temp
GO 
TRUNCATE TABLE #temp;

DROP TABLE #temp;

SELECT
    'jane' AS first_name
    ,'doe' AS last_name
INTO #temp;
```

Here's what I tried to do in the procedure, albeit unsuccessfully:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE #temp_proc 
AS
BEGIN
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temp;
    SELECT
        'john' AS first_name
        ,'doe' AS last_name
    INTO #temp;

    SELECT * FROM #temp
    GO 
    TRUNCATE TABLE #temp;

    DROP TABLE #temp;   

    SELECT
        'jane' AS first_name
        ,'doe' AS last_name
    INTO #temp;
END
```

Here's the error message I get when I attempt to create the procedure:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Procedure #temp_proc, Line 10 [Batch Start Line 0]
>   Incorrect syntax near '#temp'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 20
>   Incorrect syntax near 'END'.

**Objective**: I'd like to continue reusing the same temp table names, though I would like to stick all of this in a procedure. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sorry but no - you do not understand GO. It is a keyword that is understood and implemented by an application. It indicates to the **application** to take all preceding script text (until the beginning of the script or the previous GO) and send it to the db engine for execution.  Your procedure creation script is interpreted and executed as 2 separate batches (which is why GO is called a batch separator). The first one is:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE #temp_proc 
AS
BEGIN
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #temp;
SELECT
    'john' AS first_name
    ,'doe' AS last_name
INTO #temp;
SELECT * FROM #temp
GO
```

Followed by:

```
TRUNCATE TABLE #temp;
DROP TABLE #temp;   
SELECT
    'jane' AS first_name
    ,'doe' AS last_name
INTO #temp;
END
```

And notice that this is merely **creating** your procedure. It has nothing to do with how the procedure is executed. There is nothing to leverage here - you cannot divide your procedure definition or execution into batches using "go". So your idea and direction is, quite simply, impossible without a change. Dynamic sql is a possibility - but that is a level of complexity that will challenge and tax you.

Answer (score 2):

You can't use GO in a stored procedure. If you remove it, your code should run as expected. Although there is no need to truncate the table if you drop it later.

Comment: GO command sumit the (previous) code to SQL Server, ignoring all following instructions... (following instructions will be send after, in a seperate command)

Comment: GO is an SSMS batch separator... It's just a handy tool for doing a bunch of different things in a single SSMS tab or a single script. For example you want to deply 5 new procs from a single file, each proc definition would need to be separated by GO... A stored procedure, on the other hand, is executed as it's own batch and can't be broken into batches. Simply remove it from the procedure definition and you should be good to go.

Comment: @Bave Thank you for taking the time to respond. I fully understand the purpose and functionality of the `GO` keyword, and I was using it to my advantage. If I remove the `GO` keyword I lose the ability to reuse the temp table name, which was the point of the entire operation.

Answer (score 1):

Aside from removing the GOs in your code, you can't drop and recreate the same temp table in a stored procedure; SQL Server ignores the drop and attempts to create the same # table in the two SELECT INTO statements.

Comment: thanks for taking the time to respond. The restriction of reusing the same table name is not limited to SP's, rather it is for any code in the same batch - hence my introduction of the `GO` keyword.